# CppForms: mysql injection

Tags: c++, forms, visual-studio-2012

I have a program C++ forms and I use MySQL for the login.
in my program is vulnerability exploit

`mysqli(example : '=''or' / xxx' or 1=1 -- )`

and my question, how to fix this??

Code:

```
MySqlCommand^ connect = gcnew MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Learn.project1 where user='"+this->Tb1->Text+"' and password='"+this->Tb2->Text+"'",connect);
```

Comment: Convert all single quotes to pairs of single quotes in user input.

Comment: No, don't try to hack it out, **use parameters**!!!!

Comment: how to do it sir?